# Proof that this function does not converge to zero

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $a\ge0$, $\beta\in\mathbb{R}$, and $v_1$ and $v_2$ two fixed vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

In a certain proof I was reading, the author stated that the function
$$
e^{at}(v_1\cos(\beta t)-v_2\sin(\beta t))
$$
does not converge to $0$ as $t\to\infty$.

How can I prove this? I know that $e^{at}\to\infty$ if $a>0$ and $e^{at}\to 1$ if $a=0$, but I don't know well how to handle the expression $v_1\cos(\beta t)-v_2\sin(\beta t)$ in order to be sure that the limit does not converge to zero.

Comment: We are assuming both $v_1,v_2$ nonzero, right?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: for the k-th component:$$v_{1k}\cos(\beta t)-v_{2k}\sin(\beta t)=\sqrt{v_{1k}^2+v_{2k}^2}\sin(\beta t+\phi)$$
where $\tan(\phi)=-v_{1k}/v_{2k}$

Next, choose two different sequences for $t_n=a_n$, and $t_n=b_n$, such that

$f(a_n)\to A$ and $f(b_n)\to B$, where $A\neq B$ (maybe one of them is $\infty$) Therefore, the function doesn't converge at $t\to\infty$